# Salesforce modify standard forms for lead generation

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I would like to change the standard form for creating a lead a bit. Actually i just want to add a link to another form to allow the user to quickly jump to it (our appexchange app). I thought i could use visualforce page and override the "normal" lead creation mask. But I believe this won't work since i probably need to implement an exact copy of the normal form source code with the link additionally and also need to wire it correctly to the actions.

Since i can't find the source for the "new lead" page, it seems quite hard to do it that way. Is there any other way to add a link to a stanadard/existing form in SF ?
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cheat. Create a VF page with 2 links, 1 to your form, 1 to normal "new Lead" page. Read up about `{!URLFOR}` and the optional "no override" param (that just adds `&nooverride=1` to the url), should take users to normal form.

Failing that you might be able to use [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) (pick Aura or LWC) to magically reuse the page layout crafted by admin. You'd marry that to your VF page using [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out) - or just make your override completely an aura/lwc? It's marked as beta so I don't think you'll be able to package this as your appexchange app... Maybe provide the component and instructions for admins how they can copy paste your code to their own VF page and bypass the packaging woes.

If you really want - you should be able to recreate standard Lead layout in your VF using [Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_Layout.htm) class too. Sounds ugly but well, last resort before completely forgetting about the standard layouts, teaching admins about fieldsets and stuff?

---

Are you sure this is the right way to attack the requirement? Override (especially via VF) will be slower and if you ever create leads from related list (say Campaign -> members -> new -> add inside lookup?) you lose some flexibility. I'd make 2nd "New" list button and drop it in Lead tab or maybe add component to bottom utility bar?